# How to Create Elevated Button with Icon and Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create a button that has text and an icon by using the latest button widget ElevatedButton.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Elevated Button',
      home: FlutterExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FlutterExample extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Elevated Button with Icon and Text')),
        body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          label: Text('Elevated Button'),
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Sanjeev AV for the quick response, I got it :)

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/3e07013ad14aa92ba994cd9d1f542171
Elevated Button Example on Dart Pad

Answer (score 11):

you can add `Row()` or `Wrap()` Widget with multiple children in this case `Icon()` and `Text()`

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed:() {},
    child: Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Colors.pink,
            size: 24.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
            width:10,
        ),
        Text("Click me!", style:TextStyle(fontSize:20)),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ElevatedButton.icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html) constructor:

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                      //OnPressed Logic
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                  label: const Text(
                      "Button Text"
                  )
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ElevatedButton.icon constructor for this like

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 18),
            label: Text('My elevated button'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
```